# check number and remove leading zeros

Tags: ruby

I want to check a variable in ruby to see if it has two leading zeros (00) If it does the 00 should be removed

How can this be done

Comment: Are you looking to trim just two leading zeros? or all leading zeros?
Is this a date/time variable or just a general string?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're talking about strings:

```
str.sub!(/^00/, "")
```

The regex `/^00/` matches if the string starts with two zeros. `sub!` will then take the match (the two zeros) and replace them with the empty string.

Comment: If you're looking to replace any number of leading zeroes, just replace the regex to `/^0+/`

Answer (score 41):

OP clearly asked for removing two zeros, but a note for others that are interested in removing all leading zeros and might not be as strong in regular expressions, you can do that with this instead:

```
str.sub!(/^[0]+/,'')
```

The + is a regex special character that applies to 1 or more.

Comment: even simpler: str.sub!(/^0+/,'')

Answer (score 34):

It's pretty easy to convert to an integer and convert back to a string:

```
irb(main):007:0> s="009" ; s.to_i.to_s
=> "9"
irb(main):008:0> s="004" ; s.to_i.to_s
=> "4"
irb(main):009:0> s="00999" ; s.to_i.to_s
=> "999"
```

or, for floats:

```
irb(main):003:0> s="000.45" ; s.to_f.to_s
=> "0.45"
```

Comment: This would also remove three leading zeros or one leading zero.

Comment: True sepp2k, I forgot that. :)

Comment: "".to_i.to_s return "0"

Comment: @jrhicks: nice find. This is a little less nice but appears to fix that issue: `Integer("").to_s` --> `ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): ""`.

Comment: `Integer("008").to_s` --> `ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "008"`

Comment: Note that this also converst `"bananas".to_i.to_s -> "0"`, which may or may not be what is wanted.

Answer (score 8):

- ^ means start with
- * means zero or more

`str.sub!(/^0*/, '')`

That regexp can be used with "1234", "01234", "001234", "0001234", etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Ruby 2.5**

```
str.delete_prefix("00") # Delete exactly two zeros
```

Comment: It seems like it only deletes the first occurence: `"001".delete_prefix("0") # => "01"`